# Nested Json Decoder Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, json-deserialization

While decode the json, i getting nil response. I have nested json. whether i dont know, i'm parsing right way or not. 
Here is my code.

```
struct ProfileModelClass : Codable {
    let status : Int?
    let message : String?
    let profile : Profile?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case status = "status"
        case message = "message"
        case profile
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        status = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .status)
        message = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .message)
        profile = try Profile(from: decoder)
    }
}


struct Profile : Codable {
    let name : String?
    let email : String?
    let verified : Bool?
    let phone : Int?
    let articletype : [String]?
    let ai_score : Int?
    let bfi : String?
    let pic : String?
    let cover : String?
    let background : String?
    let layout : String?
    let customcolors : Customcolors?
    let widgets : [String]?
    let basket : [Basket]?
    let joindate : String?
    let linklink_id : String?
    let gps : Bool?
    let radius : Int?
    let showme : Bool?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case name = "name"
        case email = "email"
        case verified = "verified"
        case phone = "phone"
        case articletype = "articletype"
        case ai_score = "ai_score"
        case bfi = "bfi"
        case pic = "pic"
        case cover = "cover"
        case background = "background"
        case layout = "layout"
        case customcolors
        case widgets = "widgets"
        case basket = "basket"
        case joindate = "joindate"
        case linklink_id = "linklink_id"
        case gps = "gps"
        case radius = "radius"
        case showme = "showme"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        name = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .name)
        email = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .email)
        verified = try values.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .verified)
        phone = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .phone)
        articletype = try values.decodeIfPresent([String].self, forKey: .articletype)
        ai_score = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .ai_score)
        bfi = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .bfi)
        pic = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .pic)
        cover = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .cover)
        background = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .background)
        layout = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .layout)
        customcolors = try Customcolors(from: decoder)
        widgets = try values.decodeIfPresent([String].self, forKey: .widgets)
        basket = try values.decodeIfPresent([Basket].self, forKey: .basket)
        joindate = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .joindate)
        linklink_id = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .linklink_id)
        gps = try values.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .gps)
        radius = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .radius)
        showme = try values.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .showme)
    }

}

struct Basket : Codable {
    let mood : String?
    let score : Int?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case mood = "mood"
        case score = "score"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        mood = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .mood)
        score = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .score)
    }

}

struct Customcolors : Codable {
    let text : String?
    let opacity : Double?
    let bg : String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case text = "text"
        case opacity = "opacity"
        case bg = "bg"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        text = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .text)
        opacity = try values.decodeIfPresent(Double.self, forKey: .opacity)
        bg = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .bg)
    }

}
```

Here is my json response also

> {"status":1,"message":"Fetched data","profile":{"name":"Prem Kumar","email":"a@a.com","verified":true,"phone":"+91998532542","articletype":["fun","article","insight"],"ai_score":100,"bfi":"100%","pic":"","cover":"","background":"","layout":"3column","customcolors":{"text":"#e7e7e7","opacity":"0.8","bg":"#272323"},"widgets":["interest","education","hobbies","media","habits","profession","weather","smabusinesstypes","orderhistory","newspaper","country","wishlist"],"basket":[{"mood":"sadness","score":5},{"mood":"fear","score":4},{"mood":"anger","score":4},{"mood":"disgust","score":3},{"mood":"hate","score":3},{"mood":"jealousy","score":2},{"mood":"satisfaction","score":0},{"mood":"competetive","score":0},{"mood":"frustration","score":0},{"mood":"joy","score":0},{"mood":"elevation","score":0},{"mood":"love","score":0},{"mood":"energetic","score":0}],"joindate":"2017-12-10T07:50:06.379Z","linklink_id":"5a435b0a5c23904f78b76542","gps":true,"radius":5,"showme":true}}

Comment: Why are you specifying an initializer? The compiler gives you these for free.

Comment: oh, i will change, sometime i getting nil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the error messages. They are pretty clear

- In `Profile` the value for key `phone` is `String`
- In `CustomColors` the value for key `opacity` is `String`

Every value in double quotes is `String`, even `"0"`, `"1.0"` and `"false"`

You can delete all coding keys and all initializers because they are provided implicitly. And do not declare everything carelessly as optional. Declare only those properties as optional whose corresponding key could be missing. This particular JSON works without any optional property

Comment: we dont need to set all the keys as optional?

Comment: Yes, we don't. Try it out.

Comment: how to handle the null value, i'm getting "Expected String value but found null instead.".

Comment: In this case make the property optional.

Answer (score 0):

As @vadian rightly said, remove all the initializers and do not declare everything as optional straightaway. Identify the keys which can be missing in the response and declare only those keys as optionals. The JSON that you have provided does not require any optionals.

Just to be more clear, please check the following code

```
struct ProfileModelClass : Codable {
    let status : Int
    let message : String
    let profile : Profile
}

struct Profile : Codable {
    let name : String
    let email : String
    let verified : Bool
    let phone : String
    let articletype : [String]
    let ai_score : Int
    let bfi : String
    let pic : String
    let cover : String
    let background : String
    let layout : String
    let customcolors : Customcolors
    let widgets : [String]
    let basket : [Basket]
    let joindate : String
    let linklink_id : String
    let gps : Bool
    let radius : Int
    let showme : Bool
}

struct Customcolors : Codable {
    let text : String
    let opacity : String
    let bg : String
}

struct Basket : Codable {
    let mood : String
    let score : Int
}
```

Comment: You can even remove all coding keys. They are only needed if a property is supposed to have a different name as the key.

Comment: Thanks for the info :) Updated my answer